# Form closes but the written conditions therein not implemented

Tags: vba, forms

I have the following two codes on a button: The (first code) aims to submit value of option button into worksheet cell:

```
For Each FormControl In Me.Controls

  'Check only OptionButtons
  If TypeName(FormControl) = "OptionButton" Then

     'Check the status of the OptionButton
     If FormControl.Value = True Then
    
        'Set a variable equal to the Caption of the selected OptionButton
        OptionButtonValue = FormControl.Caption
        
        'We found the selected OptionButton so exit the loop.
        
        Exit For
     End If 
  End If
Next

'Store input in the worksheet
Sheets("Answer Sheet").Range("E80").Value = OptionButtonValue
```

To ensure an option button is selected before proceeding to next form, i have
the 'following code (second code):

```
Dim cnt As Integer
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
   If TypeName(ctl) = "OptionButton" Then
      If ctl.Value = True Then cnt = cnt + 1
   End If
Next ctl
If cnt = 0 Then MsgBox "Hello " & CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AccessReg").Range("D630").Value) & ", you 
have not selected an answer! Please select an answer to proceed to next question. Thank you.", 
vbInformation, "Please select an answer!" Else ScoreBoards.Show
Unload Me
```

MY CHALLENGES

Both codes above exists in my forms i.e. questions 1, 2, 3,...respectively, but can't seem to get the second code (that, which ensures an option button is selected before next form can be opened) to work by adding 'unload me' to the end of it, yet i want the form closed before proceeding to next. Adding 'unload me', pop-up the msgbox (which tells me to select an answer) but when i clicked okay on the msgbox, it closes the form (Question1) instead of returning me to same form to ensure an answer is clicked, then proceed to next form (Question2). However, when i remove the 'unload me', things work fine i.e. the msgbox popup when selection not made, returns to same form when okay on msgbox is clicked, and opens next form when selection made.

What i really want is: i want the second code above (which ensures an option button is selected before next form can be opened) to work as programmed and each form closed before proceeding to the next form.

Thank you in advance

PS:

The concept summary is:

- On a userform (Question1), select an option button and submit the value to worksheet
- Ensure an option button is selected:

  - if selected and button clicked, the next form(being Question2) should open
  - if not selected and button clicked, the msgbox (which tells me to select an answer), should popup
  - clicking okay on the msgbox, should return me to same form (Question1) so that i can select an option and proceed.

Comment: Which is the meaning of `Unload Me` since you do not want the form to be unloaded? Does your code have other lines after the line `Unload Me`? If yes, you should show them on your presented code. If they exist and you want to avoid executing them, just use `Exit For` instead of `Unload Me`. In this way you are not "returned", but you will not leave forward...

Comment: Thank you FaneDuru: I followed your instruction and was inspired to change the 'Exit for' in the first code to 'Unload Me', and it works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: I only now understand what you meant. Please, try using my suggestion from the answer code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adapting your second code in the next way, please:

```
If cnt = 0 Then MsgBox "Hello " & _ 
     CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AccessReg").Range("D630").Value) & ", you have not selected an answer! Please select an answer to proceed to next question. Thank you.", vbInformation, "Please select an answer!" 
     Exit For
Else
   ScoreBoards.Show
   Unload Me
End if
```